# SQL Server complicated relations cause multiple cascade path

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

My migration file generates the following sql script :

```
CREATE TABLE [Provider] 
(
    [ProviderId] INT NOT NULL,
    [BusinessId] INT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [FK_Provider_Business_BusinessId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([BusinessId]) REFERENCES [Business] ([BusinessId]) 
                ON DELETE SET NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Provider_AspNetUsers_ProviderId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([ProviderId]) REFERENCES [AspNetUsers] ([Id]) 
                ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Error :

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Provider_AspNetUsers_ProviderId' on table 'Provider' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

I'm using on delete set nulls on one of the columns, why isn't it enough ?

Business table :

```
CREATE TABLE [Business] 
(
    [BusinessId] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [OwnerId] INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Business] PRIMARY KEY ([BusinessId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Business_AspNetUsers_OwnerId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([OwnerId]) REFERENCES [AspNetUsers] ([Id]) 
                ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

The migration code that I'm using in my asp project :

```
  migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "Provider",
        columns: table => new
        {
            ProviderId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
            BusinessId = table.Column<int>(nullable: true)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_Provider", x => x.ProviderId);
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Provider_Business_BusinessId",
                column: x => x.BusinessId,
                principalTable: "Business",
                principalColumn: "BusinessId",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.SetNull);
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Provider_AspNetUsers_ProviderId",
                column: x => x.ProviderId,
                principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm using on delete set nulls on one of the columns, why isnt it enough ?

Because that's still a cascading action in the database.  You need to set Restrict, or NoAction (which are basically the same thing here).

Comment: So basically, in SQLSERVER, I need to handle all the cascading in the application If I have complex data models ?

Comment: No.  Just some of the cascading. :)

Comment: So basically, If I have x FK, and x-3 of those FK have a FK to the same orig table I'll need to handle x-3 cascades ? correct me if I'm wrong ;)

Comment: and another question, the do-nothing option, it will leave an orphant record that will point to a value that doesnt exist in the orig table ?

Comment: `x-2` actually.  You can have cascading on one of the FKs.  You'll never get an orphan row.  You'll get an error instead.

Comment: so what is the diff between restrict and noAction

Comment: It appears the Restrict and NoAction are identical for SQL Server.